# Python combinatorials w/o repetition - Pyncomb?

Tags: python, combinatorics

I'm trying to do some combinatorial stuff with data in Python. 
I looked the question [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python), but think that doesn't fit my needs.. 
I have data of this type...:

```
    group1-Steve
    group1-Mark
    group1-Tom
    group2-Brett
    group2-Mick
    group2-Foo
    group3-Dan
    group3-Phil
```

...and i need to make all possible combinations of three elements with only one from each group, without repetitions, saving to a list every combination.

I know in this case there are 18 possible different combinations(3*3*2=18), but don't know how could i write this code.
I ve read about the Pyncomb package, but don't know the function to apply in this case; maybe there's a function which does the job.

Hope anyone could help me...

Thanks in advance;

Peixe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
group1 = ["Steve", "Mark", "Tom"]
group2 = ["Brett", "Mick", "Foo"]
group3 = ["Dan", "Phil"]
for x in itertools.product(group1, group2, group3):
    print x
```

prints

```
('Steve', 'Brett', 'Dan')
('Steve', 'Brett', 'Phil')
('Steve', 'Mick', 'Dan')
('Steve', 'Mick', 'Phil')
('Steve', 'Foo', 'Dan')
('Steve', 'Foo', 'Phil')
('Mark', 'Brett', 'Dan')
('Mark', 'Brett', 'Phil')
('Mark', 'Mick', 'Dan')
('Mark', 'Mick', 'Phil')
('Mark', 'Foo', 'Dan')
('Mark', 'Foo', 'Phil')
('Tom', 'Brett', 'Dan')
('Tom', 'Brett', 'Phil')
('Tom', 'Mick', 'Dan')
('Tom', 'Mick', 'Phil')
('Tom', 'Foo', 'Dan')
('Tom', 'Foo', 'Phil')
```

Comment: Oh yes!!
I ve been trying with tenths of code lines, but this solution is really amazing and simple. :DD
Thank u very much, Sven!!!

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative which avoids the import is to use a list comprehension:

```
[(a, b, c) for a in group1 for b in group2 for c in group3]
```

This gives the same result as Sven's but is nice if you want to do some filtering too.

Comment: I'll give a try to this solution, as well. As I have to manage pretty huge amounts of data arranged in this way, i finally select the most efficient one. ;D
Thanks, PAG!

Comment: This may be more efficient, particularly if you change those square brackets to parentheses: for x in ((a, b, c) for a ....): ....

Comment: The most important difference between the two approaches is that `itertools.product()` can also be used if you don't know the number of groups in advance, while this approach hardcodes the number of groups.

Comment: Right, e.g. a nice pattern for generating binary numbers of size n as tuples is itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * n)

Comment: Given that the number of groups will vary in every case, think that will be more efficient using the "import" option...